# How to get the background-image of multiple divs and use them as the source of modal images with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, image-gallery

I am creating a gallery of pictures and I would like to be able to open the full-size image on click.

The issue is I am not using `img` tags, I am creating it using `div` and `background-image`.

I know how to do it for a single image using `id`, the code is below. However, I am not able to make it work with multiple divs using `classes`. This might be simple but I know basic JavaScript which is not enough for this task. I have searched a lot on this issue with no result. I've tried lightbox but couldn't make it work with background-image. Any help would be appreciated, even some tips to put me on the right path.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var img = document.getElementById("tehran");
var backgroundImage = img.style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, '');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = backgroundImage;
}
// close the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 20rem;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="img-container">
    <div id="tehran" class="img" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524567492592-cee28084482e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60)"></div>
    <div id="masuleh" class="img" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567317255448-8e6c04e22114?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80)"></div>
    <div id="zanjan" class="img" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518727577784-f62f1115eefb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80)"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content -->
    <img id="img01" class="modal-content">
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I also made some css changes to make the modal image do not overflow the page)

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.img-container .img')).forEach(function(img){
img.onclick = function() {
  var backgroundImage = img.style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, '');
  modal.style.display = "flex";
  modalImg.src = backgroundImage;
}
});
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

// close the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 20rem;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 80%;
  object-fit: contain;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="img-container">
    <div id="tehran" class="img" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524567492592-cee28084482e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60)"></div>
    <div id="masuleh" class="img" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567317255448-8e6c04e22114?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80)"></div>
    <div id="zanjan" class="img" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518727577784-f62f1115eefb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80)"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content -->
    <img id="img01" class="modal-content">
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That was great. Thank you. Now I know how to use an array. I want to create next and previous arrows to go through images while they're zoomed, as well. I forgot to mention it in the question. I have created one, but it requires a separate div for every single image in the modal section. Would you please tell me which method I should use?

Comment: @Leila, as this is completely a new requirement, I will suggest you to post a new question with the code you have tried, thanks:)

Comment: 1. save the array in a variable. 2. save the image index onclick. 3. onclick `prev` get the image on index `Math.max(index-1, 0)`, on click `next` get the image on index `Math.min(index+1, array.length-1)` (and update the current index) 4. if you want the images to loop, use `%` to jump from last to first and back

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky Thank you. I tried to do it for a couple of hours. I couldn't do it though. I know each of the commands but I can't figure out where to use them, none of the ways I do it works. I think I need to make a new post about it. And I need to learn JS a lot faster than I already am!

Answer (score 1):

You have to target all the elements (by *class*), then loop through them to attach the event (*click*).

Also since *img* has a predefined meaning, I will suggest you to use some other name as *class* other than *img*.

You can try the following way:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var img = document.querySelectorAll(".myImg");

var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.forEach(function(img){
  var backgroundImage = img.style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, '');
  img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = backgroundImage;
  }
});
// close the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.img-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 20rem;
}

.myImg {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="img-container">
    <div id="tehran" class="myImg" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524567492592-cee28084482e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60)"></div>
    <div id="masuleh" class="myImg" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567317255448-8e6c04e22114?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80)"></div>
    <div id="zanjan" class="myImg" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518727577784-f62f1115eefb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80)"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content -->
    <img id="img01" class="modal-content">
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```